# Remove spam link in an otherwise good question

Tags: discussion, edits, spam

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20519870/file-upload-progress-during-upload) and saw the link in the body for a tutorial that the OP was using and getting stuck with. That link now redirects to some ad site, that tries to get you to download some toolbar (if I remember correctly, my AV is now blocking the site completely for me).

The paragraph in question is:

> I’m following the ‘file upload progress’ tutorial of framework.zend.com. Please see this "*<link redacted>*" page and see the red colored texts that’s what I don’t understand of that tutorial. Please tell me whats wrong did I do.

I see 3 options for this:

- ### Flag as spam

  The question itself isn't spam, it's just one link within the question that's a bit iffy. Looking at the original URL, it appears that the link was a valid site when the question was originally posted, so doesn't appear to be an intentional spam post from the OP.
- ### Flag for mod intervention

  This seems a bit overkill for an otherwise good question (granted there's a lot of code dumped, but it's had a fair few upvotes). As mentioned above, the link appears to have been a valid site at the time of posting, so don't see any malicious intent from the OP that requires a telling off.
- ### Edit out that paragraph

  This seems like the most reasonable approach, but being less than 2K rep, it would be placed in the review queue, which could possibly be seen by reviewers as "too much" of an edit by removing a whole paragraph to fix just one link.

I'm leaning towards option 3, and editing out the paragraph and hope that the edit gets approved, but wanted the community's consensus on which way is best to go? If editing, what would be the next step if it were to be rejected?

I realise that the meta-effect will mean a 2K user will probably come and edit out the paragraph for me now, but just wondered about what to do in the future?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303698/how-to-deal-with-an-otherwise-salvageable-post-with-a-spam-link

Comment: ... Though looking at the linked question with the bad link, this is really quite different. I would say yes, take out the (now essentially broken anyway) link

Comment: Yes, edit it. Also, I've voted to close the question, as that is _not_ a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've edited out the whole paragraph now, just waiting for it to be peer-reviewed. Assumed that was the right course of action, but just wanted to confirm. Thanks both!

Comment: It won't be missed.  Hard to imagine the entire Q+A would ever be missed, that's one heck of a wall-of-code dump.  It has a lot of views and votes but the question was getting used as an audit in late 2013.

Comment: @HansPassant ahh didn't realise it was used as an audit. When I said "good" question, I probably meant "popular" instead, but the fact it was an audit explains that popularity.